# style.css of my custom theme is not being applied at all

Tags: themes, css, wp-enqueue-style

I am creating my own theme Wordpress, however the CSS I wrote for the theme design is not being applied at all. It's saved in *style.css* and I have applied the following in my *functions.php* file:

```
function letters_files() {
    wp_enqueue_style('style',get_stylesheet_uri(),NULL, microtime() );
    wp_enqueue_style('custom-google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC|Comfortaa|Cutive+Mono|Dancing+Script|Open+Sans|Roboto');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scrips','letters_files');

function letters_features() {
    add_theme_support('title-tag');
    register_nav_menu('FloatingHeaderMenu', 'Floating Header Menu');
    register_nav_menu('footerLocationOne', 'Footer Nav Menu (Footer Menu 1)');
    register_nav_menu('footerLocationTwo', 'Legal Footer Menu (Footer Menu 2)');
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'letters_features');
```

To make sure that the CSS itself isn't the problem, I have stripped down `style.css` to something simple to make it clear whether the CSS is working or not:

```
/*
  Theme Name: Letter Theme
  Author: me
  Version: 1.0
*/

body{
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Courier", arial;
}
```

It seems that no matter what I try, Wordpress just does not recognise the theme's CSS. Does anyone know any fixes or can anyone see if I'm doing anything wrong here?

Comment: `add_action('wp_enqueue_scrips','letters_files');` is 'scrips' a typo? try with `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','letters_files');`

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, it was a typo. I have been going back and forth looking for typos and somehow I missed it. I suppose this just shows how much someone else's eye helps quite a bit!

Answer (score 0):

As Michael in the comments pointed out, it was caused by a typo. I had just misspelled the word 'scripts' in *wp_enque_scripts*. Kudos to Michael!